# Rails 500 Error Visiting Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

On my localhost, my app works fine.  On production server (Heroku) when I visit a resources page: `http://startupcrawler.com/startups` I get a 500 error.

Here's my routes.rb:

```
StartupcrawlerRuby::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :startups
  get "home/index"
  root to: 'home#index'
end
```

And on my production server, here's what I get when I run `rake routes`:

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
    startups GET    /startups(.:format)          startups#index
             POST   /startups(.:format)          startups#create
 new_startup GET    /startups/new(.:format)      startups#new
edit_startup GET    /startups/:id/edit(.:format) startups#edit
     startup GET    /startups/:id(.:format)      startups#show
             PATCH  /startups/:id(.:format)      startups#update
             PUT    /startups/:id(.:format)      startups#update
             DELETE /startups/:id(.:format)      startups#destroy
  home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)        home#index
        root GET    /
```

Anything else I should check to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you executed `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Just for future general reference, here are some ways to investigate certain types of errors on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages

Comment: To those that closed this question: Is this actually the same question (environment-wise) as the duplicate that is linked?  The other question looks like it was specifically for an Apache/Passenger environment... and this question is for a Heroku environment.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

run `heroku logs -t` within project dir and try visit your resource.